# getting segmentation fault- core dumped error in shortest process next algorithm

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int n=4;
    int bt[4];
    bt[0]=6;
    bt[1]=8;
    bt[2]=7;
    bt[3]=3;
    int at[4];
    at[0]=1;
    at[1]=1;
    at[2]=2;
    at[3]=3;
    int shortest=INT_MIN;
    int minm= INT_MAX;
    int t=0;
    bool check= false;
    int complete=0;
    while(complete!=n)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if(bt[i] > 0 && bt[i] < minm  && at[i] <= t)
            {
                shortest=i;
                minm= bt[i];
                check=true;
            }
        }
        if(check=false)
        {
            t++;
            continue;
        }

        bt[shortest]--;
        minm= bt[shortest];

        if(minm=0)
        {
            minm=INT_MAX;
        }


        if(bt[shortest]=0)
        {
            complete++;
            check=false;
        }
        t++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

This is the code for shortest process next algorithm. I tried running this program in c#, it works perfect but when I implement this algorithm using c syntax in linux, it is giving me a segmentation fault- core dumped error. 
Can somebody please help resolve this?

Comment: It might not be related to the problem, but you have a typo here: `if(bt[shortest]=0)` That should be `==`. Your test will never succeed, so you'll never increment `complete`.

Comment: You have the same typo in most of the other `if` statements. Try fixing them and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Yea that's exactly what was happening @Barmar, commenting while loop and executing runs without seg faults.

Comment: This is a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Using a debugger you can step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Mistakes like the assignment instead of comparison would be very easy to find then.